# SQL - ordering results by child attribute in a parent-child join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'd like to know if there is a solution for the following situation.

I have a table `SALE(id, client_name, total)` 
and another table `SALE_ITEM (id, sale_id, item_name, item_price)`.
The relationship between `SALE` and `SALE_ITEM` tables is 1:n.

If I'd do a join between `SALE` and `SALE_ITEM` could i still (only via SQL) retrieve the results ordered by the item_name for each sale?

e.g.:

```
SALE
id          client_name                  total
1           John                          200
2           Aaron                         1400
3           Christian                     500

SALE_ITEM
id          sale_id               item_name                item_price
1           1                     Ruler                    100
2           1                     Crayon                   100 
3           2                     Bike                     1100
4           2                     Gloves                   300
5           3                     Jeans                    500

SALE JOIN SALE_ITEM (afer the ordering by sale_item#name field)
sale_id     sale_client_name     sale_total     sale_item_id    sale_item_name
2           Aaron                1400           3               Bike
2           Aaron                1400           4               Gloves
1           John                 200            2               Crayon
1           John                 200            1               Ruler
3           Christian            500            5               Jeans
```

As it can be observed from above, the results are ordered after the `SALE_ITEM#item_name` field (see Bike, ..., Crayon, ..., Jeans) , with the mention that the `SALE_ITEM` entries that belong to the same `SALE` are next to each other.

Comment: Maybe you want to order by sale.client_name, then by sale_item.item_name?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the rows in the order that you need:

```
SELECT
  S.*, SI.*
FROM
  SALE S JOIN SALE_ITEM SI
  ON S.id = SI.sale_id JOIN
  (select SALE_ITEM.sale_id, min(item_name) as min_name
   from SALE_ITEM
   group by SALE_ITEM.sale_id) SI_MIN
  ON S.id=SI_MIN.sale_id
ORDER BY SI_MIN.min_name, SI.id
```

I'm sorting firts by the `min_name` for every sale, and then by SI.id. Please [see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc6e7/9/0).

Comment: Thanks  @fthiella for the answer and for pointing me to sqlfiddle.com website. I've played a bit with the solution you've proposed and made my own fiddle based on it which delivers what I was expecting. For info, my changes can be found here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f722e/1 . I used also the mysql related ROWNUM trick found here : http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/09/13/rownum-simulation-with-mysql/ since there's no support for it in mysql.

Comment: @marius_neo you're welcome, thanks you too! rownum simulation is a nice trick and very useful sometimes, but I think that you can order by `ORDER BY SI_MIN.min_name, SI.id, SI.item_name` to have the same result. Results might differ in case when more than one client buys the same item: I'm always sorting by the first item and then by SI.id, while in your query the order of clients with the same item might vary, but it should be okay as well

Answer (score 0):

```
select sale_id, client_Name, total, sale_item.id, item_name
from sale 
inner join sale_item on sale.id = sale_item.sale_id
order by sale.id, item_name
```

Comment: I got also this far, but i would like to have Bike as the first row in the resultset

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM SALE S
 JOIN SALE_ITEM SI
   ON S.id = SI.sale_id
 ORDER BY SI.sale_id, SI.item_name
```